# Insert statement in variable declaration has error PLS-00103 (when using case)

Tags: variables, plsql, case, oracle12c, declaration

I'm using the below insert statement to declare v_text.
also i am using case in the select statement. But i am getting the below error in the case statement.

```
Error(469,119): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VALUE" when expecting one of the following:     * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || member submultiset 

 v_text := 'INSERT INTO temp_value '||
           '(ach_id, language, value, value_ivi, dq_nr, unit, leervalue, gg_id)'||
           'SELECT '||p_ach_id||', d.lfd, w.sprache,'||
            case when y.zeige_unit = 1 then regexp_replace(w.value,'(\d+\.\d+)','\1'||w.unit)  else 
             w.value end value,||
            'w.value, w.value_ivi, '||i||', w.unit, w.leervalue, w.gg_id '||
           ' FROM ZUL_GEN_NEU_Zwischenvaluee_value w
           Join DV_FORMAT_POS_DATENQ y
              ON w.dq_id = y.for_pos_dat_id,'||
           ' (SELECT /*+ no_merge(v) */ DISTINCT v.lfd'||
                  ' FROM   '||
                  '( '||p_vv_text||') v'||
                  ' JOIN ('||v_def_text||') d '||v_def_where||') d '||
           ' WHERE w.ach_id = '||p_ach_id||
           ' AND w.pos_id = '||p_pos_id||;
```

Comment: Standard debugging question, have you tried eliminating lines and sections until the error goes away?  If so, what did that exercise tell you about where the error exists?  Off the top of my head, it doesn't look like you've escaped the single quotes for the arguments to `regexp_replace`.  But assuming your intention is for this to become a SQL statement that you subsequently dynamically execute, your join logic is broken-- not sure if you're trying to join to the subquery with the `no_merge` hint-- and you should be using bind variables where possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have all of your variables, but as a start:

```lua
 v_text := 'INSERT INTO temp_value '||
           '(ach_id, language, value, value_ivi, dq_nr, unit, leervalue, gg_id)'||
           'SELECT '||p_ach_id||', d.lfd, w.sprache,'||
            case when y.zeige_unit = 1 then regexp_replace(w.value,'(\d+\.\d+)','\1'||w.unit)  else 
             w.value end ||  -- removed "value,"
            'w.value, w.value_ivi, '||i||', w.unit, w.leervalue, w.gg_id '||
           ' FROM ZUL_GEN_NEU_Zwischenvaluee_value w
           Join DV_FORMAT_POS_DATENQ y
              ON w.dq_id = y.for_pos_dat_id,'||
           ' (SELECT /*+ no_merge(v) */ DISTINCT v.lfd'||
                  ' FROM   '||
                  '( '||p_vv_text||') v'||
                  ' JOIN ('||v_def_text||') d '||v_def_where||') d '||
           ' WHERE w.ach_id = '||p_ach_id||
           ' AND w.pos_id = '||p_pos_id; -- fixed "||;"
```

(I set the SO language to Lua as it seems to display quoted text better.)